# Issue with window service using Fredi Component

Tags: service, edi

I have window service which uses fredi component to generate 810 (Invoices)

```
I have scheduled window service on server using system credentials. and its 
executes on time and giving status OK (Executed Successfully).
But it will not generate 810 invoices.
```

While i am logged on a server or i will execute manually, then it will work properly and generates 810 (invoices).

Now my Question is why it is not generating 810 (Invoices) while system user is not logged on a server?

Answer (score 0):

the way you describe this screams: 'rights problem'.
check paths (are you using UNC's?)

Comment: I am not aware of that UNC's please describe how to resolve this problem.

Comment: What @eppye means is that is sounds like you're trying to access a file that might not have the correct permissions under the windows service.  Are you referencing a local path (F:\Myfile.txt) or UNC (\\myserver\myfile.txt)?  Is there an access / permissions issue at play here?